# Android Intents - Default value on Target class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My target class is PlanetInfoActivity but I always receive the default value. I've seen some examples here with people experiecing the same issue but it's usually them constructing a new intent or receiving invalid type.

```
public static class PlanetHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlanetInfoActivity.class);
        int i =  mPlanet.getPlanetNumber(); <-- returns int

        intent.putExtra(PLANET_NUMBER, i);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

PlanetInfoActivty

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.planet_info_ui);

     Intent intData = getIntent();
     int planNum3 = intData.getIntExtra("PLANET_NUMBER", 101);


     Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(planNum3), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




}
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `PLANET_NUMBER`? Because in `PlanetHolder` you use a final static (I guess) and in your activity, you use the text "PLANET_HOLDER"

Comment: It's a string using the private static final modifiers.
How could I get access to it?

Comment: Should it have been final static?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. What is the value of it?

Comment: It's "com.example.Miguel.planeadapter". I used it as a key for the putExtra method. Whereas int i on my OnClick @PlanetAdapter is the actual planet number I get from my getPlanetNumber method

Comment: Then that's the problem. You're putting the int with  a different key you're getting it

Comment: So how would can I access the same key from a different activity? Would I just use getIntExtra(PLANET_NUMBER, 101);

Comment: If it is declared public, you can use PlanetHolder.PLANET_NUMBER

Comment: Thank you! That definitely solved it!

Comment: You're welcome. I will formulate an answer, please accept it so the question is marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get the default value, because you're putting the int with a different key than you're getting it. When you put the int in the extras you use the (probably `public static final`) variable `PLANET_NUMBER` while you're using the text `"PLANET_NUMBER"` to get the int from the extras. These values do not match. To get the int in your `PlanetInfoActivity` you must use the same key. To do so, change this line

```
int planNum3 = intData.getIntExtra("PLANET_NUMBER", 101);
```

into this

```
int planNum3 = intData.getIntExtra(PlanetHolder.PLANET_NUMBER, 101);
```